# SELECT with preferencial conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an question, I have a table in a PostgreSQL and I need to do one query to retrieve some data.

The problem is, I need select just 1 organism of each species, but each genome has different category under same species , like:

```
|ID --------------- | Organism ---------------- | Category  
|1 ---------------- | E. coli ----------------- | representative  
|2 ---------------- | E. coli ----------------- | reference  
|3 ---------------- | E. coli ----------------- | na  
|4 ---------------- | B.subtitle -------------- | representative  
|5 ---------------- | B.subtitle -------------- | na
```

So, under this example i need to choose 1 of each species (exist another column that represent Organism using a integer would be better to use than text type column), the condition to select is:
 - Select AWAYS Category: reference first
 - If no exist reference, select representative
 - If no exist reference and representative select from any category

The result of the query will be:

```
|ID --------------- | Organism ---------------- | Category   
|2 ---------------- | E. coli ----------------- | reference  
|4 ---------------- | B.subtitle -------------- | representative
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking exactly for `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (organism) t.*
from t
order by organism, ( category = 'reference') desc;
```

How does this work?  `Distinct on` is a Postgres extension.  It returns exactly one row for each unique combination of the keys in parentheses.  Which row?  The first row defined by the `order by`.

The `( category = 'reference' ) desc` logic just puts the reference category (if any) first for each organism.